# Limitting data in tables MySql

Tags: mysql

I have a lot of entries for some devices in one table, and I have to limit size for every device:

```
ENTIRES
-ID
-DEVICE_ID
-TIMESTAMP
-VALUE
```

I want to limit to e.g. 100 entries for each device. In mongo I would use capped collections. How can I do it in MySql?

I can periodically run count and delete queries, but maybe are there some better solutions?

Answer (score 1):

Count the number of entries with the DEVICE_ID

```
SELECT count(*) from ENTIRES where DEVICE_ID = <device_id>
```

Then each time you want to add an entry in the first table, check the corresponding count and if less than 100 do your insert

I read you can do conditional insert but i'm not sure it can be applied to your case

Comment: Why not use count function? I want to always insert new values, and remove older

Comment: Using count is a good idea, i was editing my answer to use count

Comment: If you want to keep the 100 new values then if you auto_increment ENTIRES.ID you could "select * from ENTIRES where DEVICE_ID = <device_id> order by ID" then remove the entry with the smaller ID after adding your new entry.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a before save trigger to remove entries from the table (if the count is > 100) before inserting the new row